# how to design checkboxlist without label in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, checkboxlist

i have a checbox list as shown in the picture below can any one tell me how design this in asp.net C#.newbie to asp.net c#

[image]

Comment: just not add text to the check box - the rest can be a table, or some divs

Comment: Please read [ask] and the [FAQ]. After this is done, please edit your question.